# $.getJSON triggers error on second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

Here's my jQuery function:

```
function MyJSON(query){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'SmartShopCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
    $.getJSON( api+query+'&jsoncallback=?', function( data ) {
      if (data['cmd']){
        if (data['cmd'] == 'ListProducts' && data['products']){
            DisplayProducts(data['products']);
        } else if (data['cmd'] == 'ProductSizes' && data['sizes']) {
            DisplayProductSizes(data['sizes']);
        } else if (data['cmd'] == 'ColorOptions' && data['colors']) {
            DisplayColorOptions(data['colors']);
        }
      }
    }).fail(function(jqxhr){
        $('#ss_msg').html('An error occured while receiving data');
        alert(jqxhr.responseText);
    });
}
```

The `.fail()` callback function is triggered only when `&cmd=ColorOptions` and only for the second call of the `$.getJSON` function. Third time, second time, etc . . . no problem!

`jqxhr.responseText` appears undefined.

Now, this is how I solved it:

```
function SmartShopJSON(query){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'SmartShopCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
    $.getJSON( api+query+'&jsoncallback=?', function( data ) {
        ...
        Bla Bla Bla
        ...
    }).fail(function(jqxhr){
        $('#ss_msg').html('An error occured while receiving data');
        alert(jqxhr.responseText);
    });
    var dummy = data['cmd'];
}
```

Please notice my 'fix' using `var dummy = data['cmd'];` at the end. It's crazy, but that did it! When I remove this line, the error comes back!

Since `alert(data['cmd'])` as a test gave not only a correct response, but also prevented .fail() from triggering, this was the solution!

But why? I'd like to know why I got the error in the first place! Any ideas?

Comment: This makes no sense, the added line has nothing to do with the ajax call, and it's executed long before the ajax call completes, at which point `data` would be undefined, and that line is also outside the scope of the callback function, so `data` would be undefined anyway.

Comment: like adeneo said, it makes no sens! And beside that, JSONP can't even get into .fail, its not supported... is this a cross-domain call anyway?

Comment: Yes. It's cross-domain. Reason for posting this is, that believe it or not, it doesn't work without this stupid line on every second call of the function. It makes no sense to me too! `fail()` IS supported, because it also triggers on timeout or when I disconnect from internet.